# Error “ssh: Name or service not known” while using mpirun in Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, mpi, mpich

I have successfully compile MPICH library in my linux cluster and also export  the variable in `~/.bashrc`.

```
# MPICH
export PATH="$/disk2/usr/lib/mpich/bin:$PATH"
```

But while I use `mpirun` for multi-core computation. The error would appear like this:

`ssh: Xiehost: Name or service not known`

**Xiehost** is my linux cluster's name. And I use `ssh` to control it.

The `.exe` was successfully execute with one core. And `mpirun` is essential for my project with better efficiency.

Any advice would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your OS doesn't now how to resolve a name **Xiehost**. Try adding in /etc/hosts (Windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts) a pair of values `IP-address Xiehost`

Comment: After adding the hostname into `/etc/hosts`, the mpich2 works fine.